# Am I missing a subtle joke in the "edit profile" page or is there a typo?

Tags: support, profile-page

When the "About me" textarea is empty on the profile edit page, the following text is in a muted color in the background:

> BY DAY: Alt-Rock Ninja Cowgirl at Veridian Dynamics.
>
> BY NIGHT: I write code and code rights for penalcoders.example.org, an
>   awesome non-profit that will totally take your money at that link. My
>   kids are cuter than yours.
>
> FOR FUN: C+ Jokes, Segway Roller Derby, NYT Sat. Crosswords (in
>   Sharpie!), Ostrich Grooming.
>
> "If you see scary things, look for the helpers-you'll always see
>   people helping."-Fred Rogers

Is the:

> FOR FUN: C+ Jokes...

a subtle joke that I'm missing or is it supposed to be C++ jokes?

This is obviously the ***HIGHEST PRIORITY*** issue on StackOverflow if it is a typo, so I'd like to know if I should sound the klaxons and make sure this gets in front of Mr Spolsky immediately.

Comment: It's [C+ jokes obviously!](https://www.google.ca/search?q=c+plus+drink&sa=X&biw=1691&bih=750&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&ved=0CCwQsARqFQoTCIegy-2YpscCFQY8PgodmH8AOQ&dpr=1). Tasty!

Comment: Ah, I should have known it was a reference to a regional beverage.  I am *so embarrassed*.

Comment: Pretty sure that's meant to mean slightly above average jokes. Not a lowly C, but not good enough for a B-.

Comment: Jokes are so much funnier when you have to have them explained to you.  And segway roller derby sounds awesome.  I'd watch that.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan Makes sense.  Using anything beyond a B+ joke is just being an exhibitionist.

Comment: @ryanyuyu especially when driven backwards. It feels like it will be more fun when people don't see it coming. But obviously this must all be a big lie as ostrich grooming sounds even more boring than watching someone do SO reviewing on a live stream.

Comment: @Gimby but...ostriches.

Comment: C+ jokes are C# jokes that are kinda dull

Comment: True story: once, before I had set my user profile description, I opened it up to look at it, and lo and behold I found all that text. My immediate thought after reading it was "somebody hacked into my account and set my description to this crazy nonsense!" I then clicked on it to edit it, and quickly realized my stupidity. (But really, it should be more obvious that it's placeholder text.)

Comment: This was carefully crafted to be just wrong enough to inspire SE users to write something else.  You fell for it.

Comment: Well I don't know about you, but for fun I program in C plus tell jokes.

Comment: @HansPassant Truly they are the puppet masters!

Comment: So that was the only thing that stood out to you? Everything else was normal except that *one* typo?

Comment: Watch out for giant, lower case Js ...

Comment: This is a failed attempt from the designers at being funny. *Failed* because 1) it is full of (US-centric?) references that a lot of SO users will not understand, 2) it leads to confusion (as demonstrated by your question and Jashaszuns comment), and 3) humor is very personal: what one person considers funny, another will find boring.

Comment: @JanDoggen Wow, you managed to say _It's not funny_ and _Humor is personal..._ in one post. I for _two_ find it funny (and I'm not from US).

Comment: @TravisJ It's not my place to judge.  If someone wants impeccably groomed ostriches, that's within his/her rights.

Comment: I feel like if there was no joke to begin with, we have made it into multiple jokes.  Good job everyone.

Comment: C+ jokes are about as big a joke as you want to tell; anything better usually hurts your lower back ...

Comment: In a college compilers class, you might make a compiler for a subset of a C-family language. Our professor called ours C--. Clearly, C+ is a subset of C++ designed for educational purposes and "C+ Jokes" are the result of all the fun you have in a college compilers class

Comment: I guess that is a hint to C with Garbage Collector

Comment: I don't think those are US-centric references. I've never been to an Ostrich groomer.

Comment: C+ is reference to the quality. A C+ joke could be a pun, or slipping on a banana peel. Clearly not grade A joke in hizear.

Answer (score 54):

> 8 bytes walk into a foo-bar. "What can I get you?" "Make us a ...

These are actually unfinished C# jokes.

You'll note that the `+` is not, in fact, a plus symbol, but an unfinished sharp sign.

[image]

---

You'll notice this entire post is barely a `+`

Comment: Plus, I get to make a pun.

Comment: I toyed with 10 word play jokes before I settled on that. I was trying to find one that related to programming, but no pun in ten did.

Comment: Webster on the plus side, your answer to this question is pretty sharp imo.

Comment: So what type of joke is it when [it skews up/down instead of slanting to the right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language))?

Comment: Plus one for the image. I can't un-C it now.

Comment: This is really clever.  I'm torn between accepting this and the recursive answer that suggests that people stare into future-telling orbs at StackExchange HQ.

Answer (score 37):

It's a recursive joke. If you search ["C+ jokes" in Google](https://www.google.com/?q="C%2B+jokes"#safe=active&q="C%2B+jokes"), this thread is now the first result.

Comment: So it's also a *prophetic* joke?  Can the SE team tell me what will be funny tomorrow?

Comment: When I search "C+ jokes", Google has [something else in mind for me](http://i.imgur.com/XGqA6WD.png).

Comment: This thread's now the first Google result for me, YMMV.

Answer (score 20):

I guess it is just the grade, in the US they grade from A (best) to F (worst) afaik. So a C+ joke would be a mediocre joke. Or maybe jokes that are barely passing as one (student reference).
The more interesting question is now: are C++ jokes funnier or not? I guess if C++ is the same as B then yes, but if I increment C, it's D afterwards right? So I just stick with the good old C jokes ;-)

Comment: Hold on a minute... isn't the increment of `C+` a `B-`?

Comment: @J.D.Ray sounds reasonable... thinking further: a programming language called B- or inferiorC would be an interesting marketing strategy

Comment: @J.D.Ray Maybe he got confused by the fact that the B# == C.