# Is this a typo in the Stack Overflow Documentation's "Add Introduction" Placeholder?

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

Recently, I tested the new [Topic Introductions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338676/documentation-update-november-29th) that have been added in the Stack Overflow Documentation. When adding an introduction to the topic (by clicking the plus button next to the "Introduction" title), an editor pops up with the following placeholder text:

> Tell the readers what they will find here and let future **contributers** [sic] know what belongs.

As far as I can tell, contributers is a misspelling and not a variation (and [Wiktionary agrees](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/contributer)) - does this need to be corrected to "contributors"?

Comment: Reminds me of the [C+ joke](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302441/am-i-missing-a-subtle-joke-in-the-edit-profile-page-or-is-there-a-typo)

Comment: +1 because it's not the British spelling.

Comment: My IDE has no built-in spell checking.

Comment: @JarrodDixon Who needs a built-in spell checker when you have end users that will catch the typos for you?

Comment: Thanks for the fix @JarrodDixon. I give it a C+!